# range selection not working as expected with where (pandas)

Tags: pandas, where-clause

I am trying to replace values between a certain range with a string, but the `where` command is not working as expected. values between 7 and 14 should be recoded as 'week1'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,6,8,10,8], 'b': [9,10,19,18,0]})

pd.DataFrame(df.where((df <=7) & (df >=14 ), 'week1'))
```

this will give the following output

```
    a   b
0   week1   week1
1   week1   week1
2   week1   week1
3   week1   week1
4   week1   week1
```

though the expected output is

```
    a   b
0   1   week1
1   6   week1
2   week1   19
3   week1   18
4   week1   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your inequalities are swapped. There are no numbers less than 7 and greater than 14.

EDIT: `where` is also the inverse of `mask`. To use where, you need only replace `&` by `|`, as you are specifying the entries *not* to be replaced by `week1`.

```py
df.where((df < 7) | (df > 14 ), 'week1')
```

Comment: you don't need `pd.DataFrame()` so removed that